# Android contacts manager with a dark theme/mode

Tags: android, information-management, contact-manager, personal-information-management, dark-theme

I've been looking for an Android contacts manager with some basic features, and I've been surprised by how hard it has been to find one.

***Requirements:***

1. Has its own dark theme/mode (does not rely on Android).
2. Is reliable.  No frequent crashes.
3. Does not require the internet or attempt to make internet connections.
4. Has a way to use one finger to quickly scroll to all names that begin with a desired letter.
5. Sorts properly when sorting by first name field.
6. No ads.
7. Does not require root privileges.

That's it.  Sounds pretty basic, but so far I haven't found anything that meets those simple requirements.

***Optional preferences*** (none are requirements):

1. Open-source.
2. Gratis.
3. Has a tile mode for favorite/frequent contacts.
4. No extra elements cluttering the UI for WhatsApp, Google products, or other junk.

If it is not gratis, any price is fine as long as it is a 1-time cost, and not a subscription.

---

*What I've already tried:*

1. `Contacts, Dialer and Phone by Facetocall` - Does not meet requirements #1 and #3.  Sketchy app behaviour.
2. `Dialer, Phone, Call Block & Contacts by Simpler` - Does not meet requirement #3.  *Very* sketchy app behaviour.
3. `Next.Phone With Dialer, InCallUI, Contacts` - Does not meet requirement #1.  No new releases for over a year, so unlikely to change.  Besides not meeting requirement #1, looks good and performs well..
4. `OpenContacts` - Does not currently meet requirements #4 and #5.  Great idea, but very buggy.
5. `Simple Contacts` - Does not currently meet requirement #2.  Crashes when scrolling.
6. `Simple Dialer` - Does not currently meet requirement #2.  Crashes when scrolling.